# Ignore NA in Ifelse statement- R

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have the following ifelse statement.

```
ww.LIG = ifelse( (Accel2$wk.VWD >= 3 & Accel2$we.VWD >= 0 ) 
             | ( Accel2$wk.VWD >=2 & Accel2$we.VWD >=1 ) 
             | ( Accel2$wk.VWD >=1 & Accel2$we.VWD >=2) , 
             (Accel2$wk.LIG + Accel2$we.LIG)/2, NA)
```

The final line takes the average of two variables if the above conditions are met. For data that meets the first criteria in the first line (Accel2$wk.VWD >= 3 & Accel2$we.VWD >= 0 ) there is an NA for the variable named Accel2$we.VWD, which obviously returns a NAN when trying to do the calculation.

What is a simple way to remove NAs form this argument?

Many thanks.

Comment: Use mean with na.rm = T to calculate the mean?

Comment: Yes, row mean with na.rm = T.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem with something like `rowMeans(..., na.rm=T)`?

Comment: you need to post a reproducible example of input and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this in two ways I think:

1) Another ifelse before this to check for NAs - something like:

```
ww.LIG = ifelse( is.na(Accel2$wk.VWD) | is.na(Accel2$we.VWD), NA,
             ifelse( (Accel2$wk.VWD >= 3 & Accel2$we.VWD >= 0 ) 
                 | ( Accel2$wk.VWD >=2 & Accel2$we.VWD >=1 ) 
                 | ( Accel2$wk.VWD >=1 & Accel2$we.VWD >=2) , 
                 (Accel2$wk.LIG + Accel2$we.LIG)/2, NA))
```

2) Remove the NA rows to start with - something like:

```
df = complete.cases(data.frame(wkVWD = Accel2$wk.VWD, weVWD = Accel2$we.VWD, Accel2$wk.LIG, weLIG = Accel2$we.LIG))
df$wwLIG = ifelse( (df$wkVWD >= 3 & df$weVWD >= 0 ) 
         | ( df$wkVWD >=2 & df$weVWD >=1 ) 
         | ( df$wkVWD >=1 & df$weVWD >=2) , 
         (df$wkLIG + df$weLIG)/2, NA)
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ill-defined: what should be the result of the following comparison NA >= value, true or false? Define this first.

I will consider an NA in the conditions means the condition is not satisfied (the sum of `a + b` is just an optimisation, it can be two separate conditions as well:

```
a = Accel2$wk.VWD
b = Accel2$we.VWD

ww.LIG = ifelse(!is.na(a + b) & 
                ((a >= 3 & b >= 0) | (a >= 2 & b >= 1) | (a >= 1 & b >= 2)), 
                (Accel2$wk.LIG + Accel2$we.LIG)/2, NA)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may be going about it the hard way. I can't tell for sure without a sample of your data, but I think you can just replace your "averaging" line with

```
mean(c(Accel2$wk.LIG , Accel2$we.LIG), na.rm=TRUE)
```

It's not clear whether you wanted to keep inputs containing `NA` values or not.

Comment: and how exactly a single mean across both datasets without any preconditions answers the author's question?

Comment: As I said, Mr. Grouchy @OlegS. , it's not clear from the question what the desired operation actually is.

Comment: It is not clear whether outcome by NA should be true or false, which in your "solution" plays no role at all. The rest if fairly clear in the question! Anyway, is it smart to answer a question that you do not understand (even if you think it is the author's fault that you do not understand the question)?